# Cross Thread error disposing form with Timer

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, error-handling

I have a timer set for 10 seconds at one of my windows form. And for the OnTimedEvent, i set for the form to be disposed after the time has been up. However there seems to be an error of

> InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code.
>
> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'notificationForm' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

The error was on the line

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

the code for my timer event is

```
    private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }
```

Anyone know how to fix this? thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are using the `System.Timers.Timer`.

Try using the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instead and subscribe to the `Tick` event.

If you have to use that Timer, you could try changing your code to this:

```
private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { this.Dispose(); });
}
```

Comment: hi. thank you for your reply. just wana know, what is the difference between system.windows.form.timer compared to the normal timer?

Comment: The Timers.Timer is a server based timer, which is why it's on a different thread than your form. The windows timer runs on the same thread as the GUI-- which is why for a winforms application, it is generally the more appropriate timer to use.  The timer in the ToolBox is the Forms.Timer.

Answer (score 1):

Or just:

```
this.Invoke((Action)(() => { this.Dispose(); }));
```

You can do this in one line:

```
timer1.Tick += (_, __) => { this.Invoke((Action)(() => { this.Dispose(); })); };
```

Answer (score 1):

As the others have stated, the problem is your timer is running a thread and trying to dispose of an object that was created on another thread. You need the dispose method to invoke on the form before it attempts to access it.

Basic thing to watch out for, if you ever try to change a presentation object created in the designer from another thread, you need to check if invoke is required.

```
void OnTick()
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(OnTick));
    else
    {
        Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Invoke(new Action(() => this.Dispose()));
}
```

This works as it is